Doctrine describe mapping to have foreign key as primary key with xml
I found how to do it with attributes at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.2/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity, but is there a way to do the same with XML?
I tried like this
        <id name="user_id" type="string" />
        <one-to-one field="product" target-entity="App\Entity\User" orphan-removal="true">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
                <cascade-remove/>
            </cascade>

            <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" />
        </one-to-one>

and it's failing with error  Property App\Entity\Address::$user_id does not exist 
I also tried like this
 <one-to-one field="product" target-entity="App\Entity\User" orphan-removal="true">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
                <cascade-remove/>
            </cascade>
             <id name="user_id" type="string" />
            <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" />
        </one-to-one>

and error is  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\Address". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.  

I found the solution, key here is to add association-key="true", like this
  <id name="user" association-key="true" />
        <one-to-one field="product" target-entity="App\Entity\User" orphan-removal="true">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
                <cascade-remove/>
            </cascade>

            <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" />
        </one-to-one>

